# PowerBI One measure split by dimension

Tags: ssas, powerbi, olap-cube

I have an Olap cube which contains one measure `Sales`.  Then I have a dimension called `Version Type` containing the values "Actual", "Budget", etc.

```
| MeasureType | Sales |
|-------------|-------|
| Actual      | 900   |
| Budget      | 1000  |
```

When I try and use a Gauge in PowerBI i put my measure `Sales` into the Value and Target, but i can't say "Sales measure filtered by Actual" and "Sales measure filtered by Budget".

Is this possible?  Do I have to create distinct measures to use this tool?

Comment: It is not possible. Yes, you need distinct measures for that. You can only select different aggregations for visual input variables.

Comment: Thanks i guessed as much - i ended up playing with a KPI and grabbing the distinct values that way - still comes with lots of extrapolation which i was trying to avoid!!

Comment: "still comes with lots of extrapolation which i was trying to avoid" - can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Well there are actuals for Order Intake, Revenue, etc and then Versions for Budget, Targets, Revised Forecasts... to make a KPI for each becomes many